# Tikz: edges overlapping with other edges and nodes on graph

Tags: graphs, network

The code below produces a graph that is difficult to interpret because the nodes and edges are overlapping. I referred to another [Stackexchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309317/tikz-nodes-overlapping-with-edges-on-graph) for a solution but it seems not to work in this case. Can anyone explain how to prevent the edges overlapping with either each other or with nodes to make the graph more readable?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 12mm,
V/.style = {circle, draw, font=\sffamily, minimum size=2em, inner sep =2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small\sffamily, sloped}
                        ]
\node[V] (s) {s};
\node[V, right=of s]       (j4)    {j4}; 
\node[V, above =of j4] (j3)    {j3};
\node[V, above =of j3] (j2)    {j2};
\node[V, above =of j2] (j1)    {j1};
\node[V, below =of j4] (j5)    {j5};
\node[V, below =of j5] (j6)    {j6};
\node[V, below =of j6] (j7)    {j7};  
\node[V, right=of j4]       (t)    {t}; 
\path   (s) edge [red, "30"] (j1)
(s) edge [red, "40"] (j3)
(s) edge [red, "5"] (j7)
(s) edge [blue, "13"] (j4)
(s) edge [blue, "3"] (j5)
(s) edge [blue, "18"] (j6)
(s) edge [green, "14"] (j5)
(s) edge [black, "18"] (j2)
(s) edge [black, "15"] (j7)
(j3) edge [red, "1"] (j1)
(j7) edge [red, "1"] (j4)
(j6) edge [blue, "2"] (j3)
(j5) edge [green, "2"] (j3)
(j2) edge [black, "1"] (j1)
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess (again) that you  are probably looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 12mm,
V/.style = {circle, draw, font=\sffamily, minimum size=2em, inner sep =2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep = 1pt, font=\footnotesize\sffamily, sloped}
                        ]
\node[V] (s) {s};
\node[V, right=of s]   (j4)    {j4};
\node[V, above =of j4] (j3)    {j3};
\node[V, above =of j3] (j2)    {j2};
\node[V, above =of j2] (j1)    {j1};
\node[V, below =of j4] (j5)    {j5};
\node[V, below =of j5] (j6)    {j6};
\node[V, below =of j6] (j7)    {j7};
\node[V, right=of j4]  (t)     {t};

\foreach \i/\j [count=\k]   in {30/red,  18/black, 40/red,      
                                13/blue, 14/green, 18/blue,
                                15/black}
\path   (s) edge [\j, "\i"] (j\k);
    \begin{scope}[bend right=45]
\path   (j3) edge [red,   "1"] (j1)
        (j7) edge [red,   "1"] (j4)
        (j6) edge [blue,  "2"] (j3)
        (j5) edge [green, "2"] (j3)
        (j2) edge [black, "1"] (j1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

- for shorter code are arrows from node `s` to nodes `j...`  drawn in the `foreach` loop
- further shortening code can be done by using `chgains` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below,
     V/.style = {circle, draw, font=\sffamily, minimum size=2em, inner sep =2pt},
       every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep = 1pt, 
                            font=\footnotesize\sffamily, sloped}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,7}
    \node[V, on chain]   (j\i)    {j4};

\node[V,  left=of j4]   (s) {s};
\node[V, right=of j4]   (t) {t};

\foreach \i/\j [count=\k]   in {30/red,  18/black, 40/red,      
                                13/blue, 14/green, 18/blue,
                                15/black}
\path   (s) edge [\j, "\i"] (j\k);
    \begin{scope}[bend right=45]
\path   (j3) edge [red,   "1"] (j1)
        (j7) edge [red,   "1"] (j4)
        (j6) edge [blue,  "2"] (j3)
        (j5) edge [green, "2"] (j3)
        (j2) edge [black, "1"] (j1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is the same as before.